# No decoration on links in CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink, text-decorations

[Example page](http://saucydares.freehostia.com/saucy.php),
[Accompanying CSS](http://saucydares.freehostia.com/saucy.css)

Should be a fairly basic issue but for some reason I can't figure it out.

Basically I want the links in my navbar to have no underline or colour change and remain white.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The source code is missing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you're selecting the main `.links` element, but not the actual `a` elements inside. This should do the trick:

```
.links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```